# Solving a flexible multi-depot multi-vehicle VRP with OR-tools

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to solve a seemingly unique VRP using OR-tools where I have a number of depots, each with a capacity constraint and a number of vehicles, also with a capacity constraint.

I then have a number of parcels I can drop off to any of the depots for delivery by the vehicles.

So for example, let's say I have:

- 1000 parcels to deliver across a city (they are currently at a national hub)
- 8 depots across the target city - each of which can store up to 200
  parcels
- 20 vehicles within the city - each of which can carry up to 50 parcels (from
  any depot)

How do I:

- know which parcels I should drop off at which depot from the national hub
- know which vehicle(s) should collect which parcels from which depot in order to perform the last mile deliveries
- calculate the optimal routes (based on route duration) each vehicle should take

Ideally the solution would be something like:

- Drop off these 180 parcels to this depot, these 190 parcels to this depot etc
- Get this vehicle to collect these 45 parcels from this depot, this vehicle...
- For this vehicle deliver the parcels using this sequence, for this vehicle...

I've looked at the [start/end points](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_tasks#setting_start_and_end_locations_for_routes) for vehicles but this only work if that is a fixed known.

Comment: Simple column generation seems better suited to solve this. I do not get the (source, destination) for each parcel. Are these postal hubs where you need to move parcels before the last mile part ?

Comment: @LaurentPerron yes it would be moving the parcels from a central hub to more local depots ready for last mile delivery - I've updated the question